# Is any one of these the right way to write a license for your opensource project forked and modified from an existing one with different authors?

Tags: java, licensing, open-source, github, bsd

I've used parts of source from an existing Java library project with what appears to be a 3-clause BSD license.

I've made significant changes to the library which makes it possible to use it in a new platform, and also added several new features, and new example projects using the modified library.

I want to know if any one of these is the correct way to write a license for the project (no change in type of license)

Please read both versions and provide a comparative answer:

EITHER:

```
**<New library name for another platform>**

**Copyright (c) 2014
new author name**

**All rights reserved.**

**This project incorporates code from the project titled
<original library name for different platform> 
which has its source code repository at
<git repository link> with the following copyright holders:**

**Copyright (c) 200x-200y
original library author name 1
original library author name 2
original library author name 3**

**All rights reserved.**

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:

    Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

    Neither the name of **<author name>, <old library author name 1>,
    <old library author name 2>, <old library author name 3>**, nor the names of its
    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
    this software without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER
OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```

OR:

```
**<New library name for another platform>
Copyright (c) 2014
new library author name
All rights reserved.**


Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:

    Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

    Neither the name of **<new library author name>**, nor the names of its
    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
    this software without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER
OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.


**This project incorporates code from the project titled
<original library name for different platform> 
which has its source code repository at <git repository link>
and which is covered by the following terms:**

**<Original library name for different platform>
Copyright (c) 200x-200y
original library author name 1
original library author name 2
original library author name 3
All rights reserved.**

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:

    Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

    Neither the name of **<original library author name 1>,
    <original library author name 2>, <original library author name 3>**,
    nor the names of its
    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
    this software without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER
OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```

Comment: This is not a site for legal advice. Please consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you copied parts of the other library into your library, the authors/copyright holders of the parts you copied must also be mentioned as (joint) copyright holders of your library. For that reason, neither option is correct.

A correct way to provide the right copyright and license informations is

> Copyright 2014 <original author names>, <new library author>
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
>
> *This library is derived from the <XXX> library, which is distributed under the same license terms and can be found at <URL>.*

In the copyright line, you give proper attribution to all persons/legal entities that can claim copyright on *parts* of the code.
The mention of the library you based your work on is not required, but shows you are a nice guy who is not out to steal other one's credits. As it is distributed under the same license, there is no need to reproduce the license again.

Comment: Good one, Bart. The copyright notice is the important thing, but acknowledging the work of others is absolutely the right thing to do.